# Why is the restriction of an automorphism in the Galois group an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

So there is this proof in advanced modern algebra by Rotman that I have a question about. The conditions in the theorem are let $k\subset B\subset E$ be a tower of fields if $B/k$ and $E/k$ are normal extension.

The proof goes like this:

Since $B/k$ is a normal extension, it is a  splitting field of some $f(x)$ in $k[x]$; that is, $B=k(z_{1},\dots,z_{t})\subset E$, where $z_{1},\dots,z_{t}$ are roots of $f(x)$. If $\sigma\in Gal(E/k)$, the restriction of  $\sigma$ to $B$ is an automorphism of $B\dots$

now the part I don't understand is why is $\sigma$ necessarily a automorphism of $B$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $B$ is the splitting field of a family $\cal F$ of polynomials, then any action $\sigma$ (even from above) preserves the set of roots of $\cal F$, and since $B$ is generated by these roots the action $\sigma$ preserves $B$ in a setwise sense, i.e. $\sigma B=B$. Therefore it can be restricted.

It still satisfies all of the properties of being a field automorphism, just on $B$ now. For example, if we have $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$ and $\sigma(x+y)=\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)$ for all $x,y\in E$, then *in particular* these two relations also hold for all $x,y\in B$ because $B\subset E$.

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I should have looked at the action of $\sigma$ on a roof of $f$ before asking this question.